# Save XML retrieved with rest and php

Tags: php, xml, save

I can retrieve certain information with a rest command, the data it shows (in the browser) is already an XML. How do I save it to an XML file on the server after retrieving the information.

I have already tried it with the $dom-save command but I seem to do something wrong. Any help would be appreciated. See below for code (I want to save the $response to XML.)

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/rest_connector.php';
require_once 'includes/session.php';

// check to see if we start a new session or maintain the current one
checksession();

$rest = new RESTConnector();

$url = "/api/tax_codes/0/";
$rest->createRequest($url,"GET", null, $_SESSION['cookies'][0]);
$rest->sendRequest();

$response = $rest->getResponse();
$error = $rest->getException();

// save our session cookies
if ($_SESSION['cookies']==null) 
$_SESSION['cookies'] = $rest->getCookies();

// display any error message
if ($error!=null)
echo $error;

// display the response
if ($response!=null)
echo $response;
else
echo "There was no response.";  


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RESTConneconnector is a specific class Lightspeed. I solved it by using this:

```
ibxml_use_internal_errors(true);//load if improperly formatted
file_put_contents("exportProduct.xml", $responseProduct);
```

So it was very easy in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know any about RESTConnector class. But I suppose, you can try something like it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($response->asXML());
$dom->save($this->fileexport);
```